# How to make an attachment download link for a webmail using IMAP and PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink, download, imap, attachment

I'm working on a mobile webmail project, and I'm currently looking for a way to create a link (or a list of links) to allow webmail users to download attachments on mails. It would look like :
`<a href="???">title of the file.ext</a>`

I can already get the attachments and display it as an awful wall of special chars, but I can't find the way to create a link to download the attachment after displaying the email content.

Does anyone have a guess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the force-download header to the client.

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.zip\"");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("file.zip"));
```

The content-length is not entirely necessary.

You will have to create a php script which will be linked liked this:

```
<a href="http://server/script.php?emailId=12345&fileName=file.zip">
```

And the PHP script will just send the headers above and print full contents of the file.

Comment: Er, why would you have that `Content-Type` header? Seems like an abuse without cause. `Content-Disposition: attachment` is enough to make the file download as at attachment, instead of in a tab, isn’t it?